# Compile-time recursion with SFINAE as template argument

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I was playing around with templates, and I wanted to use them to write a recursive function that will be evaluated during compile-time. And I want it to branch depending on the number that I pass to it. The function does have a constraint; I want to keep the return value.

So this was my attempt to write the function (it doesn't compile):

```
template<int n, typename std::enable_if_t<n==1>>
constexpr auto fun() { return std::make_tuple(1); }

template<int n, typename std::enable_if_t<n==2>>
constexpr auto fun() { return std::make_tuple(fun<1>(), 2); }

template<int n, typename enable = void>
constexpr auto fun() {
    return std::tuple_cat(fun<n-1>(), n);
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = fun<4>();

    return 0;
}
```

The issue that I'm facing is that I'm not sure where to put the `std::enable_if_t` statement, and how to write it exactly to assure that my function branches correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here.  `std::tuple_cat(fun<n-1>(), n)` is not correct because `n` is not a tuple.  `tuple_cat` expects all parameters to be tuples.

Comment: Seconding NathanOliver's comment. If you could show a *non*-recursive `fun3` that's equivalent to your desired `fun<3>`, I think that would clarify a lot.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. But yeah, I was looking to do what Timo wrote. Thanks for showing me the issue with the std::tuple_cat though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to concatenate your tuple and create it in the form of

```
fun<4>() == tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

you can write two templates like

```
template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n == 1>* = nullptr>
constexpr auto fun() 
{
    return std::make_tuple(1); 
}

template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n != 1>* = nullptr>
constexpr auto fun()
{
    return std::tuple_cat(fun<n-1>(), std::tuple(n));
}
```

However, that's not the *"C++17 way"*  of doing this. It can be expressed much nicer by using `if constexpr`

```
template<int n>
constexpr auto fun2()
{
    if constexpr (n > 1)
        return std::tuple_cat(fun2<n-1>(), std::tuple(n));
    else
        return std::tuple(1);
}
```

Regarding sequence creations (things like `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`) there is also [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) which can be used in combination with template parameter packs

```
template <int... nums>
constexpr auto construct(std::integer_sequence<int, nums...>)
{
    return std::tuple((nums + 1)...);
}

template<int n>
constexpr auto fun3()
{
    return construct(std::make_integer_sequence<int, n>());
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Acm_Cp) is a full example.

Comment: `fun2<0>()` is valid whereas `fun<0>()` isn't. ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 that's true, although the result is unexpected in either case :D. Technically, `fun<0>()` is vaild. The compiler will die during instantiation but the program should be well defined.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! The if constexpr is an even better solution. Although, I'm not completely sure why do I need a pointer to std::enable_if_t in the first example? Can I not just use it without a pointer?

Comment: @Maki that's because we need a non-type template parameter with a default value. `typename = enable_if_t<...>` doesn't work because it introduces a type rather than a value. If you don't specify a type for `enable_if`, it uses `void` as a default (i.e. `enable_if<true> == enable_if<true, void>`). Since we can't assign a value to a `void` type, we make it a `void*` which can take any pointer. We could also write `enable_if<true, int> = 0`. The result would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear for me what do you exactly want but... let me guess: you want something as follows

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n==1, bool> = true>
constexpr auto fun() { return std::make_tuple(1); }

template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n!=1, bool> = true>
constexpr auto fun() { return std::tuple_cat(fun<n-1>(), std::make_tuple(n)); }

int main() { constexpr auto x = fun<4>(); }
```

The trick

```
template<int n, typename enable = void>
```

is a SFINAE trick for template class, where there is the main version and some specialization; so the main version define the signature and the specializations a SFINAE enabled/disabled through `std::enable_if`.

With functions you have overloading of functions but not partial specialization. You have to enable/disable every single overloaded function indipendently

```
template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n==1, bool> = true>
// ...

template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n!=1, bool> = true>
// ...
```

Observe that I have written

```
template<int n, std::enable_if_t<n==1, bool> = true>
```

and not

```
template<int n, typename = std::enable_if_t<n==1>>
```

The second form also works to enable/disable a single function but doesn't works when you have different functions with the same signature (as in your case) and you want enable only one version.